# Toast notifications are not working on a JavaScript call

Tags: javascript, c#, android, xamarin.android, android-toast

I'm developing an App with Xamarin.Android and I want to show a Toast notification while I'm exporting a report from JavaScript. My app calls the report and it's successfully generated. However, the Toast notification is never displayed. I discovered that only when I set a break point in that specific line it's shown in Visual Studio 2017.

This is part of my C# class for handling JS.

```
class CallJSInterface : Java.Lang.Object
{
    private class Timetable
    {
        public string member { get; set; }
        public string role { get; set; }
        public string time { get; set; }
        public string lastColor { get; set; }
    }

    private Context context;
    public CallJSInterface(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    [Export]
    [JavascriptInterface]
    public void ExportToExcel(string results)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(context, context.GetString(Resource.String.LblExportMsg), ToastLength.Short).Show();

        var timetable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Timetable>>(results);

        //Excel conversion
    }
}
```

This is the value for the *LblExportMsg* in the Strings.xml:

```
<string name="LblExportMsg">Exporting your Agenda to Excel.</string>
```

Also, this is an example of I call the function in JS:

```
$("#linkDownload").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    CSharp.ExportToExcel('[{"member":"Luis","role":"Timer","time":"00:15:15","lastColor":"red"},{"member":"Luis","role":"Timer 1","time":"00:15:00","lastColor":"green"},{"member":"Luis","role":"Timer 2","time":"00:15:17","lastColor":"red"},{"member":"Luis","role":"Timer 3","time":"00:07:15","lastColor":"green"},{"member":"Luis","role":"Timer 4","time":"00:23:15","lastColor":"red"},{"member":"Luis","role":"Timer 5","time":"00:15:15","lastColor":"green"},{"member":"Luis","role":"Timer 6","time":"01:15:15","lastColor":"yellow"},{"member":"Luis","role":"Timer 7","time":"00:18:15","lastColor":"green"},{"member":"Luis","role":"Timer 8","time":"00:15:22","lastColor":"green"}]');
});
```

Additionally, the HTML button:

```
<button type="button" id="linkDownload">Export</button>
```

Finally, this is how I add the JS interface to the WebView from the main activity:

```
webView.AddJavascriptInterface(new CallJSInterface(this), "CSharp");
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Is it something related to the context? How can I check it? Thanks for your help.

PS:

- The minimum SDK is 21 and targets the SDK 27.
- I'm using [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for deserializing.

Comment: Please share your js code.

Comment: Hi @YorkShen-MSFT, it's there, this is how I'm calling the method:
CSharp.ExportToExcel("");, nothing special, I just shared a JSON instead of the empty string, which it's fully working because it exports the excel successfully. Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on my side, so please share a basic demo or more complete code so that we could reproduce this issue on our side.

Comment: No problem @YorkShen-MSFT, I added more code and an example of the JSON that I'm expecting

Comment: That's wierd, it should be work. Would you mind sharing a basic demo that could reproduce this problem through an online repo?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If you could share a basic demo to reproduce this problem that would be really appreciated! Just to make sure we are verifying the exact same thing you are using.

Comment: Hi @YorkShen-MSFT, not exactly, I am migrating the code to Bootstrap Alerts, they are working as expected. I'll continue on the weekend.

Comment: Thanks and look forward to your reply. :)

Comment: Hi @YorkShen-MSFT, I provided my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix it, I added a timeout before exporting the report and also, split in two the process one for displaying the Toast and another for the report.

```
$("#linkDownload").click(function (e) {
    CSharp.Alert(currentTranslation.lblExportMsg);
    setTimeout(function () {
        CSharp.ExportToExcel(JSON.stringify(results));
    }, 250);
});
```